# Django handle requests with theading

Tags: python, django, multithreading

I have a Django project which make predictions on a VM with 2 CPU cores and 8 RAM. When my Django app starts it loads a large file (2.5GB, time to load:10 sec.) with information that the app needs. My app can handle a large amount of concurrent requests till I get error but it only use the 50% of my CPU (1 core), in order to use the 100% of my machines power I need to activate the second core through threading.

How can I set the my app so can handle users requests through different threads ?

Is there a recommended way to do that or an example ?

Comment: Python has not really a good implementation of "multithreading" as far as I know it "mimics" multithreading, but still uses one core. You will probably need to use "multiprocessing" instead.

Comment: This is entirely a function of how you configure your server process, which you haven't described.

Comment: I use IIS and FastCGI to host my app. With  FastCGI I can set it to use 2 python cells but there is an issue, both python cells load the data so the app consume 5+GB of RAM and its too large. So I have to implement this process in my code.